# SQL - Display sales this month and last month in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2018 and I have a single table called SALES, which looks something like this

```
SALES_PERSON_ID MONTH   SALES
001             Aug-20  3
002             Aug-20  2
003             Aug-20  0
001             Sep-20  4
002             Sep-20  2
003             Sep-20  3
```

Each new month is added to the table, which will show the accumulative sales for each sales person.

I want to summarise this data as sales this month vs last month, which I've done like this:

```
SELECT 
   tb1.SALES_PERSON_ID
  ,SALES_THIS_MONTH
  ,SALES_LAST_MONTH
FROM 
   (SELECT SALES_PERSON_ID, MONTH, SUM(SALES) AS SALES_THIS_MONTH 
    FROM SALES
    WHERE MONTH = 'Sep-20') AS tb1
JOIN
   (SELECT SALES_PERSON_ID, MONTH, SUM(SALES) AS SALES_LAST_MONTH
    FROM SALES
    WHERE MONTH = 'Aug-20') AS tb2
ON. tb1.SALES_PERSON_ID = tb2.SALES_PERSON_ID
```

If Sep-20 is the current month, then it gives me something like this:

```
SALES_PERSON_ID SALES_THIS_MONTH SALES_LAST_MONTH
001             4                3
002             2                2
003             3                0
```

That works fine, but in reality I have hundreds of thousands of records with hundreds of months and I can't "hard-code" the dates for all possible months in a WHERE clause. I want a dynamic solution that will always provide the sum of sales for a given month and what the sum of sales was for the previous month specific to that record.

So I would need my tb2 to somehow always know which month tb1 was referring to and then subtract a month. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are missing `GROUP BY` in subqueries?

Comment: 20 years after Y2K but we continue to avoid the lessons learned. How sad!

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select s.*,
       lag(sales) over (partition by SALES_PERSON_ID order by month) as prev_sales
from sales s;
```

This assumes that `month` is really a `date`.  If it is not, you can use:

```
       lag(sales) over (partition by SALES_PERSON_ID order by convert(date, '01-' + month)) as prev_sales
```

If you want to filter this for only the most recent month, use a subquery for the `lag()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             lag(sales) over (partition by SALES_PERSON_ID order by month) as prev_sales
      from sales s
     ) s
where s.month = dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate(), -1))
```